# Arduino IDE on Attiny45: What kind of power does a chip need?

Tags: power, attiny, battery, piezo, op-amp

I have this little AtTiny45 which I'm loading a program with Arduino as ISP.

My goal to use this chip along with a op amp, a piezo buzzer and a press button, and have it automatically sleep between uses.

I intend to use 2 3V pill batteries in parallel (specifically [CR2032](https://www.amazon.ca/Maxell-CR2032-Lithium-Batteries-Version/dp/B07VH3VRCJ/ref=sxts_sxwds-bia-wc-drs-ajax1_0?cv_ct_cx=CR2032&dchild=1&keywords=CR2032&pd_rd_i=B07VH3VRCJ&pd_rd_r=dc117175-f9aa-4cd5-8c64-d6edb19fd43f&pd_rd_w=4dUsA&pd_rd_wg=ck2Vq&pf_rd_p=23dc26fa-d34b-4922-8a43-bae5e960ed0f&pf_rd_r=0402J9JTYWJM0114SW3C&psc=1&qid=1602134636&sr=1-1-25b07e09-600a-4f0d-816e-b06387f8bcf1) if this makes a difference) as the power source, so here are my two questions:

- Can 2 3V pill batteries in parallel power a small application that will produce audible sound?
- How long could these batteries last *--based on constant use--* **if someone used this item for an hour per day**?

Comment: Thanks jsotola! I've updated the question to fit more the need as I was not as clear as necessary. It has a press button which will spark a sound for a short while then resume sleep.

Comment: Everything depends on used parts, and overall current consumption... For now it's just "it might or it might not" to almost every question you have

Comment: Assuming 5mA when on, one hour a day; 2µA when sleeping the rest of the time; [I get](https://oregonembedded.com/batterycalc.htm) around 40 days of runtime. But you can probably have the MCU sleep in between task during that 1 hour of usage. You might have to find a way to turn of the opamp when it's not needed, to keep the sleep current as low as possible. I'm unsure how much current a piezo uses, but I don't think it's much.

Comment: I guess one could provide current to an opamp through a transistor?

Comment: @Gerben I followed the link very useful! Thank you